# An is a series of real numbers. Bn=An+100. prove by definition that: LimAn=L<->LimBn=L

Tags: calculus

$A_n$ is a series of real numbers.
$B_n = A_{n+100}$.

Prove by the definition that:
$\lim An =L \Longleftrightarrow \lim  B_n=L$

I'm kind of stuck. Would appreciate any help :]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=L$$
then by definition: for $\epsilon>0$, there's $N$ and for all $n\ge N$ we have
$$|A_n-L|<\epsilon$$
and since $n+100\ge N\iff n\ge N-100$ then if $n\ge N-100$ we have
$$|A_{n+100}-L|=|B_n-L|<\epsilon$$
hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}B_n=L$$
the other implication is similar and I leave it for you.

Comment: Thank you! i lacked the "right words" for this proof, after all its my first semester... you helped me a lot!

Comment: You're welcome Danny.